# ClearScript: How to output an object?

Tags: clearscript

Here is the C# code:

```
string jsScript = "var x = {A: 10, B: 100}";
scriptEngine.Evaluate(jsScript);
var result = scriptEngine.Evaluate("x");
```

The result is an instance of WindowsScriptItem object, how can I get the values 10 and 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the object's property names, you can do this:

```
dynamic dynamicResult = result;
Console.WriteLine(dynamicResult.A);
Console.WriteLine(dynamicResult.B);
```

If you don't know the property names, you can do this:

```
dynamic dynamicResult = result;
foreach (var name in dynamicResult.GetDynamicMemberNames())
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, dynamicResult[name]);
```

Obviously you'll need something more sophisticated if the object's property values can themselves be objects.

Comment: Is it possible to perform such a foreach when you use Engine.Execute method? This method is void (and also the Evaluate method),  so how to assign a result? Thanks.

Comment: `Execute` is `void`, but `Evaluate` returns a result. If that result is a script object, the above should work. You can also use the `ScriptObject` class to enumerate properties without `dynamic`, which should be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help.